# Append row to empty pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to create an empty pandas DataFrame with the columns `['ImageName','faces','ImageWidth', 'ImageHeight']` to which I'm trying to append a row. Let's take the following row as an example: `['selfie_10.png',3,200,300]`.

So far, I've come up with the following code snippet. But either it doesn't work or it throws an error.

```
import pandas as pd

columns = ['ImageName','faces','ImageWidth', 'ImageHeight']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

for i in range(0,10):
    row = ['selfie_10.png',3,200,300]
    df.append(row,ignore_index=True)
 
print(df)
```

The output is unfortunately an empty array.

```
In [72]:runfile('/Users/add_row.py', wdir='/Users/Desktop/faces')
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ImageName, faces, ImageWidth, ImageHeight]
Index: []
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: try `df.loc[i] = row` in the for loop instead of appending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, create a list and append all the rows into that list then convert that list into a DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
columns = ['ImageName','faces','ImageWidth', 'ImageHeight']
a = []
for i in range(0,10):
    row = ['selfie_10.png',3,200,300]
    a.append(row)
df = pd.DataFrame(a,columns=columns)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @MustafyAydin I've come up with this solution.

```
columns = ['ImageName','faces','ImageWidth', 'ImageHeight']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
print(df.shape)

for i in range(0,10):
    row = ['selfie_10.png',3,200,300]
    index = df.shape[0] + 1
    df.loc[index] = row
 
print(df)
```